# How to access configuration file from subfolder in Go

Tags: go, path

I got a structure of my project that looks pretty like this:

```
project/
    api/
        api.go
    config/
        config.go
        config.toml
    tests/
        api_test.go
    main.go
```

So, whenever I initialize config package I'm trying to read config file using relative path: `config/config.toml`.
This works fine as soon as I run my program: `go run main.go`

The problem appears when I try to run my tests: `go test project/tests`. My config package cannot find file `config/config.toml` because current work directory is not `project/` as in first case but `project/tests/`.

Is there any convenient way to access config file from both `run` and `test`?

Comment: Tests are run in a temp directory. You need to include the test data in the package, or provide an absolute path to the files in some other way, e.g. env variable, flag, etc.

Comment: @JimB an envvar is simpler to handle with tests than flags, that's what I usually use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've finished with changing the behavior how configuration file is being loaded. Before, the load was done in `config` packed inside `init()` method.

Instead of this I've created method `Load(path string)` that performs load of the configuration file according to `path` variable that is passed.

Now, I call it from `main.go` like this:

```
config.Load("config/")
```

And from `api_test.go` like this:

```
config.Load("../config/")
```

This is not very neat solution but in that case user is not required to specify any additional parameters while running tests.

Comment: Are you assuming your app will always run from within the source and not be deployed as a stand-alone executable, ever?

Comment: This is a poor way to handle configuration. Not to mention your binary's directory and working directory are almost never the same when you deploy an application.

Comment: @JimB, so after deployment the structure won't be the same as in `src` ?

Comment: Depends on how you're deploying, but using `go run` from within the source directory is definitely *not* how to do it. Install your binary properly, and make sure it has a way to locate a configuration other than depending on the layout of the source directory.

Comment: @WhiteAngel For configuration files I think the best way is to store them on a hidden folder in the user's home directory if it's a peruser config, or in your platform default folder like `etc/YOUR_APP` if it's global configuration.

Comment: @JimB, I see your point. Thank you for mentioning this. I will have to change this behavior after deployment for sure, but for the moment of development this way suits me really well.